# Google Sheet Query - WHERE clause to result from another query

Tags: sql, google-sheets, subquery

I am new to Google Sheet query with a SQL Server background. My worksheet is here:

[My example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11VxIsVvjKvoqKNyVEpDgv5jSx42w8QkN3zoBU7uDXKI/edit?usp=sharing)

The file contains multiple worksheets. I am trying to write a query to get Employee Number from Employee Name and then use this result to get Employee's Assignment information.

Things I have tried so far:

Query to get Employee Number from Name: (this is working fine)

```
query(Individual!A2:AL25,"select N, Q, O where AL = 'Christian Slater'")
```

The above query returns certain columns for an Employee. Column N is Employee_Number.

Query to get Assignment End Date for that Employee:

```
=query(Assignments!A1:R1001,"select * where G = (query(Individual!A2:AL25,"select N, Q, O where AL = 'Christian Slater'"))")
```

I get a formula parse error - so obviously I am not using the correct syntax.
I would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction and useful resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query(Assignments!A1:R1001,"select A where G like '"&query(Individual!A2:AL25,"select N, Q, O where AL = 'Christian Slater'")&"' label(A) '' ")
```

Comment: Many thanks @pnuts for your prompt help. This works perfectly and returns the result (2 rows).  Would you please tell me what the part "label(A)" is for? The second query is returning 3 columns (N, Q, O). Does label(A) aliases column N to A?